# How to name instance variables in VB.NET since not case sensitive

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Ok hopefully this does not get deleted because I really am interested in some input on my question but I realize it is a bit subjective.  I really like in C# when defining a varaible of a type I can use the same name but just have the 1st letter lower case to differentiate it from its type; I see it done often:

```
MyType myType = new MyType();
```

Ok I can't do this in VB.NET because it is not a case sensitive language so I end up doing all sorts of stuff (keep improving) to create a name for the variable. I realize I can use an underscore "_" in front of the type, but I don't really like that, as that is also used to denote class level variables (or 'm' is used too). So I end up always trying something like:

```
Dim Typ As New MyType()
```

Ok it works, but I like the C# way better because it makes so much sense. Just make the 1st letter lowercase.

Any suggestions other than the underscore preceeding the variable name on this topic?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, VB.NET programmers are forced to come up with more descriptive variable names.  Perhaps half the reason that it is considered more readable, not sure.  If you really can't come up with something better than "myType" then, say, postfix the name with 'Field'.  IntelliSense makes long descriptive names cheap.

Comment: Ouch got downvoted, yet there was a ton of good feedback. Hummmmm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the lower case version of the class name is actually a bad practice in actual code. It's good for use in code examples because they only show the basic function of a class. But you never use "integer" (or should not) as variable name because it describes what data is stored, not what it's used for.

Instead you should choose names that describe what the variable is used for.

Edit: It's common practice to use variable names that describe the class because the class often defines what the object is used for. Still you should choose a name specific for the situation, like if you are making a list of errors: instead of stringBuilder you should use allErrorsFound.

Edit example:

```
class Person
{
    Person friend = new Person();
    public void GetPencil()
    {
        bool pencilFound = 
            friend.AskQuestion(this, "Can I borrow your pencil?")
            .ToLower().Contains("yes");
    }

    public string AskQuestion(Person enquirer, string question)
    {
        // Analyze question implications.
        return "Decision made.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Good advice: could you please use the custom class 'Person'  and show me a code example of instantiation in VB.NET as you would do? What will I use it for? CRUD methods on the class and populating properties. Very standard generic use.

Comment: MrFox - if you can give a concrete example(s) of your reccomendations I will mark this as the answer. Use my last comment as a guide please if possible.

Comment: Thats the difficult part and the rule is not written in stone, but I'll give an example.

Answer (score 1):

[Visual Basic Naming Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b283bse%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), per Microsoft. (Found via "naming conventions VB.NET" search.)

Of course, follow house rules and be consistent.

Happy coding.

---

I only code in C#, however, my rules is: If the instance variable is *exposed* as part of the type, then UpperCase. If it is *private* ("not exposed) then camelCase.

I use an underscore prefix *only* to denote something of interest. For instance, COM objects which are not owned (mostly with local variables) or for backing variables for properties. That is, the use of an underscores in my code is to highlight something and "being an instance variable" is not very noteworthy.

Comment: Thank you I read that, but it does not speak to 'Instance' varaibles specifically in the context (or even in general) of my original question. They give no advice that answers my question. It gives some *general* guidlines but no concrete suggestions like I am looking for please.

Comment: @atconway Yes, I should have read it in detail first. I added my own rules ;-) In any case, be consistent.

Comment: However I did read that an underscore is probably not a good idea though anyways: "Element names starting with an underscore (_) are not part of the Common Language Specification (CLS), so CLS-compliant code cannot use a component that defines such names. "

Comment: @atconway Never a problem here (not saying it /won't/ be, but no CLS warnings either), then again, the only instance variables that start with underscores in my code are never exposed.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, this is infinit topic I believe. Basicaly I would suggest to not focus too much on way you write variable, even if this is important, like several ones for example:

put "_" in front of global class member fields
integer begin with "i", or whatever

**but focus that the variables that make a part of the same "domain" looks similiary. Like variables for security/password stuff have some naming conversion, for user access management may be something else, for data layer something different...**, in this case one looking on code will not just realize the type of the variable but **meaning** of it.

Regards.